# Nodejs: does any way to beautify my package.json file?

Tags: node.js, js-beautify

At first, I don't care much about my project's `package.json`, with the time flow, it become more and more complex and dirty. it's hard to handle manually.

so, is there any plugin or tool to beautify my package.json file?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to use your editor/IDE JS/JSON formatter. For Sublime Text 2/3 that would be https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JsFormat

Alternatively, you can use an online tool like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to code in JS is by using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (IDE). It has all the formatting tools required to Parse JSON properly, auto indent the code and IntelliSense which help in writing JS easy are already present in it .